# How to get shapes aligned in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, scikit-learn

I get the error message `ValueError: shapes (100,2) and (100,2) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 100 (dim 0)` when I use this code to get OLS regression results table. Should I somehow transform my data to make this work?

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from pandas import DataFrame
model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
predictions = model.predict(X)

print_model = model.summary()
print(print_model)
predictions
```

X

```
sampler = qmc.LatinHypercube(d=4)

u_bounds = np.array([5.0, 5.0, 10.0, 10.0])
l_bounds = np.array([0.125, 0.125, 0.1, 0.1])
data = sampler.lhs_method(100)*(u_bounds-(l_bounds)) + (l_bounds)
```

y

```
y=np.zeros((100,2))   
for i in range(np.shape(data)[0]):
    y[i,0], y[i,1] = objectives(data[i,0], data[i,1], data[i,2], data[i,3])
```

Comment: From the docs: `y` is expected to be 1-d; exactly what one would expect for OLS.

Comment: Without a full **traceback** we can't say exactly what's happening, but my guess is that it's trying to do a dot product.  For that the arrays have to be (100,2) and (2,100) or the reverse.  Review your array shapes, and the requirements of the function.